# renderDataTable in shiny is showing column search at bottom but I want it on top

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following code for a shiny application:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
data_for_table <- read_csv("data/ForStatAnalysis.csv") %>% select(-ElectionYear ) %>% select(-State_abb) %>% rename('Total Migration'=totalMigration)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$base_data <- renderDataTable(
  data_for_table,
  options=list(
    pageLength = 10, scrollX=TRUE 
    )
  )
     

)

})
```

This renders with search columns (which I like) however, the search columns are located at the bottom of the grid, which is just weird.
It looks like this:
[image: Grid with column search on bottom]
I have tried various options at https://datatables.net/reference/option/ but I can't seem to figure out what parameter will make the column search appear at the top of the grid.
Does anyone know how to move these column searchers to the top of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the DT library and filter="top" as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
data_for_table <- read_csv("data/ForStatAnalysis.csv") %>% select(-ElectionYear ) %>% select(-State_abb) %>% rename('Total Migration'=totalMigration)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$base_data <- renderDataTable(
      data_for_table,filter="top",
      options=list(
        pageLength = 10, scrollX=TRUE,  options = list(
          columns = list(searchable = FALSE)
        )
      )
         

    )

})
```